# libgdx, How to make my image touchable

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a button to randomly generate 4 tree images (I called them badges) on the screen. Now I want to make those badges touchable. If I touch it it simply print out a message. Currently the code looks like this.

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    int scWidth, scHeight;
    int playerWidth, playerHeight;

    Stage stage;
    Skin skin;
    BitmapFont font;
    private SpriteBatch batch; // This is in the render.
    ArrayList<Badge> badges;
    Iterator<Badge> badgeIterator;
    int badgeWidth = 160;
    int badgeHeight = 300;


    Game game;
    public PlayScreen(Game game){
        this.game = game;
    }


    // Create a button to randomise tree positions
    TextureAtlas buttonAtlas;
    TextButton.TextButtonStyle buttonStyle;
    TextButton playButton;

    int randomBadgePosition(String choice)
    {
        int min, max, range;
        if (choice == "x") {
            min = scWidth / 2 - scHeight / 2;
            max = scWidth / 2 + scHeight / 2 - badgeWidth;
            range = (max - min) + 1;
            return (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
        } else{
            min = 0;
            max = scHeight - badgeHeight;
            range = (max - min) + 1;
            return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        stage = new Stage();
        scWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        scHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        font.getData().setScale(5);

        int numBadges = 4;
        badges = new ArrayList<Badge>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numBadges; i ++){
            badges.add(new Badge(new Vector2(-400, -400),new Vector2(badgeWidth, badgeHeight) ));
        }

        skin = new Skin();
        buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("buttons/button1.txt");
        skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas); // You need to do that.
        buttonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        buttonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button");
        buttonStyle.over = skin.getDrawable("buttonpressed"); // over is not necessary for android.
        buttonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("buttonpressed");
        buttonStyle.font = font;
        playButton = new TextButton("play", buttonStyle);
        playButton.setPosition(50, 20);
        stage.addActor(playButton);


        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        // Input listener for buttons.
        playButton.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                                      int pointer, int button){
                // Randomise the locations of the badges.
                for (int i = 0; i < badges.size(); i++){
                    badges.get(i).setPosition(new Vector2(randomBadgePosition("x"), randomBadgePosition("y")));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
        batch.begin();

        badgeIterator = badges.iterator();
        // This is how to change the position of the badge.
        badges.get(1).setPosition(new Vector2(scWidth/2, scHeight/2));
        while(badgeIterator.hasNext()){
            Badge cur = badgeIterator.next();
            cur.draw(batch);
        }

        batch.end();
        player.update(); // Update the bound
    }
}
```

And the Badge class is :

```
public class Badge {

    Vector2 position, size;
    Texture badge;
    Rectangle bounds;

    public Badge(Vector2 position, Vector2 size){
        this.position = position;
        this.size = size;
        bounds = new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);
        badge = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tree.png"));
    }

    public void update(){
        bounds.set(position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
        batch.draw(badge, position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Vector2 getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(Vector2 size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
    }
}
```

I think I need to put them in stage then addlistener. While I know the addlistener part (just like the button). I dont know how modify the Badge class and constructor it differently so that it can be added to stage. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the *Scene2D* so you can use [Image](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html) class instead of creating your own implementation in `Badge` class. Of course if you need some functionalities that *Image* cannot provide you can extend this one.

`Image` class itself inherits from [Actor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) which you can add to stage and to which you can add listeners what is exactly what you want to do.

If you want to just handle *click* on the image the [ClickListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html) will be best - if you need to handle more events you can add the [EventListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/EventListener.html).

Example code could look like

```
    Stage stage;

    //...creating stage etc...

    Image badge = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tree.png"))); //Remember that you need to dispose Texture like this!
    badge.addListener( new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            System.out.println("Clicked!");
        }
    });

    stage.addActor(badge);
```

Also notice that you need to set your `stage` as input processor by using

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Comment: Thanks. because my badges is an arraylist of 4. How can I print the current position of the touched tree?

Answer (score 0):

Remember the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674054/libgdx-android-how-to-drag-and-move-a-texture)? :-) The idea is exactly the same, but instead of this:

```
addListener(new DragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                moveBy(x - getWidth()/2, y - getHeight()/2);
            }
        });
```

you add this:

```
addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
               System.out.println("Badge name is: " + ((Badge)event.getRelatedActor()).getName())
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, my first issue is that I can't just stage.addActor(badges) because badges is an ArrayList. So I used a for loop to add each one individually. Is that ok? Then my second issue (same with the player issue) is when app started as soon as I touched the screen it crashed.:(

Comment: I found out the crashes happen because of System.out.println("Badge name is: " + ((Badge)event.getRelatedActor()).getName());... So I think the way I add the badges to stage is not correct. Is there a way to add arrayList using stage.addActor?

Comment: Jiajun, yes I made up a method called getName() inside your Badge that returns the name - you can replace this with whatever you wish. For example if you want to know which item in the ArrayList was clicked, iterate through it with a for loop and see which one from the list matches a ((Badge)event.getRelatedActor())'s unique property (like the name I made up). ((Badge)event.getRelatedActor()) gives you the Badge which was clicked.

Comment: Hi WonderfulWorld. getName() is a proper method. And it return nil hence the crashing. I think it is because the way I add actor. I loop through the array list and add it individually by index. Maybe this is why when I click on the badge it doesn't have an index to return?